Weighted Sobolev space and embedding.
Let $1<p<\infty$, $s>0$ and $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution}\colon \left\|u\right\|_{H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}= \left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}<\infty\right\}$
the Sobolev space. It is know that, $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ when $s>n/p$.
Question. Let $w$ a Muckenhoupt weight. Does the weighted Sobolev space $H_w^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n))=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution }\colon \left\|u\right\|_{H_w^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\right\|_{L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}<\infty\right\}$ also satisfy the same inclusion when $s>n/p$?
